# Как привязать набор команд к RibbonGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть некоторый набор классов (неизвестный на этапе компиляции), предоставляющих набор команд, и модель представления, которая содержит коллекцию этих классов. Нужно показать набор команд в `RibbonGroup` на ленте.

Я представляю себе это примерно так. Объявляю свои классы, реализующие некий пустой интерфейс:

```
public ClassA : ISomeClass 
{
    public ICommand Command1 { get; }

    public ICommand Command2 { get; }
}

public ClassB : ISomeClass 
{
    public ICommand Command3 { get; }
}
```

Объявляем модель представления главного окна, которая содержит перечень объявленных выше классов:

```
public MainVm 
{
    public ISomeClass[] SomeClasses { get; }

    public MainVm() 
    {
        SomeClasses = new[] { new ClassA(), new ClassB() };
    }
}
```

Для представления вспомогательных классов я использую словари ресурсов:

```
// представление ClassA
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <RibbonButton x:Key="Command1_ItemKey" Label="Command1" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
    <RibbonButton x:Key="Command2_ItemKey" Label="Command2" Command="{Binding Command2}" />
</ResourceDictionary>

// представление ClassB
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <RibbonButton x:Key="Command3_ItemKey" Label="Command3" Command="{Binding Command3}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Часть представления для главной модели представления:

```
<RibbonTab Header="Home">
    <RibbonGroup Header="Main" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeClasses}">
        // вот здесь непонятно, что делать. Нужно каким-то образом связать каждый конкретный элемент со списком кнопок в представлении
    </RibbonGroup>
</RibbonTab>
```

Я могу получить коллекцию кнопок из словаря ресурсов, связанного с конкретным вспомогательным классом. Не пойму, как ее можно вставить в `RibbonGroup`.

Comment: Хм. По идее вы не должны класть в словарь _контролы_, только стили/шаблоны/whatever. Потому что у контрола не может быть два Parent'а.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы говорите, что у вас к каждому классу привязан `ResourceDictionary`. Это по идее решает проблему.

Положим в `ResourceDictionary` следующее:

```
// представление ClassA
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ClassA}"> <!-- без ключа! -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RibbonButton Label="Command1" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
            <RibbonButton Label="Command2" Command="{Binding Command2}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Таким образом, в `ResourceDictionary` объявляется View для данного VM-класса `ClassA`.

Теперь, это представление должно использоваться в риббоне. Для этого у вас есть несколько опций. Если для данных VM это — единственное нужное представление, все эти `ResourceDictionary` добавьте как `MergedDictionary` в `Application.Resources` в рантайме. Если у этих VM есть ещё и другое представление, соберите все `ResourceDictionary` и добавьте их в ресурсы конкретного `RibbonTab`'а.

Дальше ваш код должен быть просто таким:

```
<RibbonGroup Header="Main" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeClasses}"/>
```

Отображение ваших классов возьмётся из `ResourceDictionary`.

Вроде всё.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, работает. Я пытался добавить кнопки в шаблон, но не догадался положить их в StackPanel.

Comment: @Vlad: Основной трюк — это `DataTemplate`, который устанавливает, каким образом `ContentPresenter` будет отображать данный VM-тип.

Comment: @Vlad: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.

Comment: я сначала так и сделал. Но в шаблон нельзя просто взять и положить два контрола. Не додумался их в контейнер положить.